# RabbitMQ WebSocket 404 Not Found

Tags: nginx, websocket, rabbitmq, cowboy

I'm running `rabbitmq-server v3.3.5-1.1` on the `Debian v8.2`. I have enabled `rabbitmq_web_stomp` and `rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples` as per suggestion in the [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html):

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples
```

All examples exposed at `http://127.0.0.1:15670` work as intended, but they all use `SockJS` rather than native browser's `WebSocket`:

```
// Stomp.js boilerplate
var ws = new SockJS('http://' + window.location.hostname + ':15674/stomp');
var client = Stomp.over(ws);
```

I would like to stick to the `WebSocket` so I tried what was suggested in the docs:

```
var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:15674/ws');
```

This throws an error to my face:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:15674/ws' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Further tests with `netcat` confirm `404`:

```
#  netcat -nv 127.0.0.1 15674
127.0.0.1 15674 open
GET /ws HTTP/1.1 
Host: 127.0.0.1

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 23 Jan 2016 20:15:13 GMT
Server: Cowboy
```

Obviously `cowboy` does not expose `/ws` path, so I wonder:

- Is it possible to reconfigure `cowboy` in this situation? How? Is it worth it?
- May I use `nginx` in the place of the `cowboy` (*preferred option*)? How?
- What other options do I have?

***EDIT***

RabbitMQ [docs](https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html) are misleading. Correct WebSocket URI:

```
http://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp/websocket
```

Answer (score 2):

good job, but:

> new WebSocket('http://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp/websocket')

```
VM98:2 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL's scheme must be either 'ws' or 'wss'. 'http' is not allowed.(…)(anonymous function) ...
```

need to use ws/wss-schema:

> new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp/websocket')

```
WebSocket {url: "ws://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp/websocket", readyState: 0, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null…}
```